# Minimizing the toal risk under squared-error loss for normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, risk

Suppose that $X_i \sim N(\theta_i,1)$ are independent for $i=1,\dots,n$. Let:

$$\hat{\theta_i}(\boldsymbol{x^{n}})= \left(1 - \frac{b}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2} \right)x_i $$

Where $b$ is a constant. If we define the total risk under squared-error loss as:

$$R(\theta,\hat{\theta})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E \left[\hat{\theta_i}(\boldsymbol{x^{n}})-\theta_i \right]^2 $$

Show that $R(\theta,\hat{\theta})$ is minimized by taking $b=n-2$.

---

Since the $X_i \sim N(\theta_i,1)$ are independent, we know that the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2$ will be distributed according to a non-central chi squared distribution. As well, one can write $E \left[\hat{\theta_i}(\boldsymbol{x^{n}})-\theta_i \right]^2$ as the sum of the variance of $\hat{\theta_i}(\boldsymbol{x^{n}})$ and the squared bias of $\hat{\theta_i}(\boldsymbol{x^{n}})$ with respect to $\theta_i$, but I would not be sure on how to proceed by using these facts. Or would there be a better way to approach the problem?